# Did the Trolls and Kristoff know/remember Anna?

Tags: plot-explanation, frozen

In the Disney animated movie Frozen, when Anna was still young she was struck accidentally by Elsa with her Frost powers and froze Anna's heart. Anna was brought to the Trolls by her parents to heal her. At that time Kristoff saw how the trolls healed Anna.

Now when Anna was pursuing Elsa, she was again accidentally struck by Elsa with her Frost powers. Kristoff then brought Anna to the trolls again hoping that they could do something about her.

Now my questions are, did the Trolls know that it was Anna, the same girl that was brought to them a few years ago? As well as Kristoff. Did Kristoff know or remember that it was Anna that he saw few years ago healed by the Trolls?

Comment: I think he did. Who else would have the same hair? OK that sounds dumb. I dont think so. Whatever. I'll ask when I go to Disney.

Comment: Kristoff saw Anna get healed as a child? I'm gonna have to go back and watch the movie because I don't remember that at all.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Yep, when the parents are rushing through the woods to find the trolls, Elsa's powers (fueled by her extreme emotions at the time) are creating a trail of ice. As they pass by a young Kristoff and Sven he's intrigued by the ice and follows them. He watched the happenings from behind a rock, which turns out to be another troll who vows to keep the two of them, hence him being raised by trolls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Troll King remembered, as he said that he could not heal Anna as he did before.

Kristoff didn't indicate that he remembered Anna specifically, but he knew that the trolls could heal the type of injury that she had, as he told Anna, because he had seen it done before. He most likely put two and two together, since very few people have sisters with that specific magical ability.

Comment: Man I don't even remember him being there, I think the 500th time watching it my brain gave itself a partial lobotomy in self defense

Comment: Grand Pabbie did not mention healing her before, rather he said "If it was her head that would be easy" - just as when she was a child he said "The heart is not so easily changed, but the head can be persuaded", simply comparing the head to the heart. He just did the same thing again when she is older, but reversed.

Answer (score 6):

I got the impression that the trolls remembered Anna due their mystical 'all-seeing' nature.

However, Kristoff didn't remember her. I think his witnessing of the healing from the early scene in the film was purely for our benefit - we saw the event happen through his eyes.
In a way, Kristoff was the audience's eyes and ears in the film.

Answer (score 3):

No, Kristoff did not remember Anna but the trolls did. I don't think that when he was younger he was paying attention to who the girls were specifically. I think he was paying attention to the trolls.